# Unable to receive IP from DHCP when using ICS on Local Area Connection

Tags: networking, dhcp, ics

The computer fails to get the IP from DHCP when I set internet connection sharing in on. (The network reads "Unidentified Network".)

I have to manually turn it off and then connect again to get an IP and connect.
I am wondering if this is a bug.
I am using Windows 7.

Comment: What are you trying to share the internet with?

Comment: I was not sharing at the moment, I just like to keep it turned on so the whenever I need I can do a `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`.